# Prove some property of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

So we have  funtction $f(z)$ which is holomorphic in open unit disc $U=\{|z| \lt 1\}$ and continuous in its closure. I want to prove that f can be uniformply approximated with polynomials on closed unit disc

Comment: Are your polynomials in $z$ or $z,\overline{z}$?

Comment: My polynomials are in terms of $z$ only

Comment: Take a polynomial $P_n$ approximating $f((1-1/n)z)$

Comment: Why I can take such polynomial? Because  $|(1-\frac{1}{n}) z| \lt 1$? So that we can represent function as Taylor series? The how should I use compactness of closed unit disc when I take the limit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem

Comment: @gustaffIR Blech. Mergelyan's Theorem is not easy, while the present question is a trivial exercise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Since $f$ is (uniformly) continuous on the closed disk there exists $r\in(0,1)$ such that if $$g(z)=f(rz)$$then $$|f(z)-g(z)|<\epsilon/2\quad(|z|\le 1).$$Since the power series for $f$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of the open disk there exists a  polynomial $q$ such that $$|f(z)-q(z)|<\epsilon/2\quad(|z|\le r).$$Now let $$p(z)=q(rz);$$then for $|z|\le1$ you have $$|f(z)-p(z)|\le|f(z)-f(rz)|+|f(rz)-q(rz)|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2.$$

Comment: My function is holomorphic only in interior of unit disc, so that I can’t see why is $|f(z)-q(z)| \lt \epsilon /2$ holds for $|z|=1$

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO I didn't say  $|f(z)-q(z)|<\epsilon/2$ for $|z|=1$. That inequality holds for $|z|\le r$, which is all that I claimed...

Comment: oh , thank you. I’m stupid today